# Workflow Setting People/Group Field Skipping Values

Tags: workflow, column, people-picker

I have a workflow that sets the value of a person/group field in a document library.  The field is set to multiple users/groups.  The problem is that the field will skip every other user set by the workflow.

When I export the library to excel, it ends up looking like the following..

16;#16;#122;#122

Should be 4 different user IDs, but only two get set and retained.

When I add 6 users via workflow - 14;16;17;122;132;145 - The values that show in the field are 14; 17; 132. It is setting every other user.  Could this be because I am trying to set the library field to my task outcome field that gets defined via workflow?

Any ideas?

Comment: What is there in workflow? can you show ?

Comment: I'm using 'Update Item in Current Item' and setting to my variable.

Comment: from where people and group information is coming. How are you putting it in workflow ?

Comment: ah, right...my task outcome content type has the people-picker in it.  I have an 'Assign Reviewers' task that requires the field be populated.  After the task is complete, I am setting a variable to the users selected (which works just fine in actually assigning the tasks and getting the emails out).

Comment: I just added 6 users - 14;16;17;122;132;145.  The values that show in the field are 14; 17; 132.  It is setting every other user.  Something to do with the second position being a placeholder?

Comment: What are these numbers ?

Comment: Sorry, user IDs..when I export to excel, the field shows 14;#14;#17;#17;#132;#132

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to create a workaround by first setting a text field (which was showing the values correctly), and then setting the person/group field (using login names, semicolon delimited) based on what was showing in the text field.

So there is an extra step in that I have to set the text field with my workflow first in order to set the person/group field correctly, but hey, it works.

Thanks to everyone for your help!